# How to set state of response from axios in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

How do I set the state of a get response in axios?

```
axios.get(response){
    this.setState({events: response.data})
}
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You have a syntax error here. You should try this instead

```
var self = this;
axios.get('/url')
 .then(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
   self.setState({events: response.data})
 })
.catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
});
//the rest of the code
var a = 'i might be executed before the server responds'
```

There are a few things to note here:

- `axios.get` is an asynchronous function which means that the rest of the code will be executed .And when the response of the server arrives, the function passed to `then` will be executed. The return value of `axios.get('url')` is called a promise object. You can read [more about it here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261)
- `this` keyword has a different value depending of where it is called. `this` in `this.setState` **should** refer to the constructor object, and when you call `this` inside a function, it refers to the `window` object. That is why i assigned `this` to the variable `self`. You can read [more about this here](https://toddmotto.com/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript/)

**Pro tip:**

If you use ES6, you would want to use arrow functions (which don't have their own `this`)  and use `this.setState` without assigning `this` to a variable. [more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
    axios.get('/url')
     .then((response) => {
       console.log(response);
       this.setState({events: response.data})
     })
    .catch((error)=>{
       console.log(error);
    });
```

Here is a complete example https://codesandbox.io/s/rm4pyq9m0o containing **best practices** commonly used to fetch data including error handling, try again and loading. This provides a **better User experience**. You are encouraged to modify the code and play around to get more insights about it.

Comment: Hello, I know I too late to respond but this answer saved my lots of time and effort. Thanks

Comment: Could not figure out what was wrong in my code, lucky I stumbled upon this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

This isn't working because "this" is different inside of axios. "this" inside axios refers to the axios object, not your react component. You can resolve this with .bind

Also axios isnt being used properly.

it should look something like

```
axios.get("/yourURL").then(function(response) {
  this.setState({ events: response.data });
}.bind(this));
```

Alternatively if using es6 you could sub out the function for an arrow function and get the same effect without bind

```
axios.get("/yourURL").then(response => {
  this.setState({ events: response.data });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply try this node js

```
      axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
       .then(res => {
          const persons = res.data;
          this.setState({ persons });
      })
```

if you are using **react js** then you first import in component than use axios

like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
        this.setState({ persons });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have dealt with promises similar to that in the past when I was learning react. What I did was put the api call on the `componentDidMount` method and set the state to an initial value. I used a loader while the data was being fetched.

```
componentDidMount() {
 const self = this;
 axios.get(response){
  self.setState({ events: response.data });
}
```

As of now, I would use something similar to what checkenrode said.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this:

```
  var self= this; // self will now be referred to your component

  axios.get("http://localhost:3001/get_user?id=" + id)
  .then(function (response) {
    if(response.data.rows != null)
    user_detail = response.data.rows;
    console.log(response);
    self.setState({email: user_detail.name, name: user_detail.name})
  })
```