# Coping with "Can only update a mounted or mounting component"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise, axios

I am trying to domesticate this Axios beast and I wrote the next code:

```
class AxiosTable extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);


    this.state = {
         products: [],
    };


    this.reloadProducts = this.reloadProducts.bind(this);
    this.assignState = this.assignState.bind(this);
}


assignState(response_data) {

    var json_data = response_data;
    var lproducts = [];

    for(var i in json_data)
        lproducts.push(json_data [i]);

    console.log(lproducts);

    this.setState({products: lproducts});

  }


reloadProducts() {
    self = this;
    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/allProdsExample').then(function (response) {
    console.log('----------------------------------------==============');
    console.log(response.data);

    self.assignState(response.data);
    });

}

componentDidMount(){
    this.reloadProducts();
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <BootstrapTable data={this.state.products} height='120' scrollTop={ 'Bottom' }>
            <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='price'>Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
         </div>
     );
  };    


}
```

---

My console posted the next message:

```
----------------------------------------==============
mod3bundle.js:556 (2) [Object, Object]
mod3bundle.js:1840 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the AxiosTable component.
```

I followed past examples like:  [How to set state of response from axios in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194866/how-to-set-state-of-response-from-axios-in-react)

to make my solution. Yet that warning makes my table to show nothing. I am also calling my code on the componentDidMount function and that makes me feel this problem shouldn't happen. I truly need  your assistance please.

ADDITIONAL INFO:  Based on:
https://medium.com/@TaylorBriggs/your-react-component-can-t-promise-to-stay-mounted-e5d6eb10cbb

I added the next methods:

```
componentDidMount() {
     this._isMounted = true;
     this.reloadProducts();
 }

componentWillUnmount(){
    this._isMounted = false;
}
```

and the table started to show up values. Any explanation why? I am still trying to understand that article. Thanks

MORE REFERENCES:
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: Though this is theoretically the correct place to load your data, this can lead to problems as well (eg: switching pages so that the component will unmount, would throw the given error). Maybe you should check if your component wasn't unmounted do to another change on your page. Any chance you could create a MVCE? It is btw a warning, not an error, so you should be fine ;)

Comment: Do you need to parse the response? `JSON.parse(response.data)`

Comment: It is not necessary to parse with JSX. But, while it says a warning the data I am trying to use from the setState seems to be not available for the use in the Bootstrap table

Comment: I added a modified version for the assignState function. Just this change did not allowed me to see the table rows but the adding of componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount did. Now I want to understand what's going on!