# update state from ajax call on componentdidmount -react

Tags: ajax, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to update the state variable from ajax response. I tried below

```
componentDidMount() {
   var parent_object=this;
          axios.get('/template.php')
                  .then((result)=> {
                      console.log(result.data);

   parent_object.setState({component_template:result.data})//not updating

                  });

    console.log("here");
    console.log(this.state.component_template);
}
```

I can see the array for `result.data` but the state variable `component_template` is not updated

I tried 
[How to set state of response from axios in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194866/how-to-set-state-of-response-from-axios-in-react)
and 
https://daveceddia.com/ajax-requests-in-react/
but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.

So the state might be updating properly, but your console.log might not be able to read the updated value. Try using the callback, or check inside `componentDidUpdate` .

Answer (score 3):

React setState is asynchronous!
You can call a callback function after the state value has updated:

```
componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('/template.php')
              .then((result)=> {
               console.log(result.data);
                this.setState({component_template:result.data},()=>{
                   console.log(this.state.component_template);
                 })

      });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

setState in react is a asynchronous call. Console after the setSate doesn't guarantee the updated value.

Add console either as callback with setState  or inside the render method as a first line to check the updated state value.