# TypeError from axios get on a json endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am getting the data I need from the response, but I get a TypeError and I don't understand why? What do I need to do to fix this?

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const getData = axios.get("https://web-code-test-xxx-games-prd.appspot.com/cards.json")
      .then(function(response) {
        const easyResponse = response.data.levels[0]['difficulty']
        const easyCards = response.data.levels[0]['cards']
        this.setState({ easy: easyResponse})
        this.setState({easyCards: easyCards})

       })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

}

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: TypeError{}, I've looked around for more verbose explanations, no luck. Is it because its fetching a json?

Comment: this is the response                                                             
  Object {data: Object, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: Object, 
   config: Object…}
   data: Object
  levels: Array[2]
  0: Object
  1: Object
  status: 200
  statusText: ""
  headers: Object
  config: Object
 request: XMLHttpRequest

Comment: The TypeError is coming from how I setState

Answer (score 0):

The TypeError was not in the get request, it was coming from the Promise object that was returned. Axios is an asynchronous action and the 'this' is lost/ different inside Axios thus the 'this' in this.setState was not being read properly. By switching to an arrow function the 'this' is no longer the axios object but the context object, the react component. Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194866/how-to-set-state-of-response-from-axios-in-react).