# Why 'this' is undefined inside a Promise call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand what's going on

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    //const self = this; 
    let _id = this.props.match.params.id.toUpperCase();

    if (_id != this.state.id.toUpperCase()) {

        axios.get('/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=' + _id + '&tsyms=USD')
            .then(response => {
                // let _currentcoin = { ...resp.data.RAW.BTC.USD, ticker: _id };
                this.setState({ id: _id }); //this == undefined
            });
    }
}
```

I can get a response back but `this` is always undefined and I'm unable to `setState`. I'm using an arrow function which I thought was scope 'this' to the component level. I can fix it by making a new var and setting `'this'` before I make the request. I know that `this` should be working though. What am I missing?

My entire component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from '../../axios';


class CoinViewer extends Component {

state = {
    coin: {},
    hasLoaded: false,
    id: ''
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    //const self = this; 
    let _id = this.props.match.params.id.toUpperCase();

    if (_id != this.state.id.toUpperCase()) {

        axios.get('/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=' + _id + '&tsyms=USD')
            .then( resp => {
                // let _currentcoin = { ...resp.data.RAW.BTC.USD, ticker: _id };
                this.setState({ id: _id });
            });
    }
}

componentWillMount() {

}

componentWillUpdate() {


}

componentDidUpdate() {

}

getCompleteCoinData(_id) {

}


render() {


    return (
        <div>
            CoinViewer Component: {this.state.id} sads
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default CoinViewer

Comment: I am using the same approach, but with fetch. It seems to be working !!

Comment: You should be able to use the arrow function to access the `this` context of your component. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194866/how-to-set-state-of-response-from-axios-in-react

Could you share the code for your whole component?

Comment: not able to reproduce your issue, I tried something similar to your code, but it worked for me. https://codepen.io/smilesaayush/pen/VdKoJa
If I don't use arrow function after axios response then it gives error, but otherwise it works.

Comment: If I declare let self == this and then self.setState(...) it works. I never had to do that for any other axiom promises. It's a bit confusing for me

Comment: maybe try logging what `this` is in every step to see if its what you expect. also verify you are able to use arrow functions in other places in your code so you know its not a transpiler error

Comment: *Unless I'm missing something*, you either (1) have some non-standard enigmatic manually-driven garbage collection going on, which somehow manages to delete the component instance before the `then` callback runs, (2) have a buggy transpiler, or (3) simply did not copy the original code to your question ([Occam's razor principle](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) applies). The code in your question *should* work.

Comment: i think the error message for this line `this.setState({ id: _id }); //this == undefined` is actually undefined is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:Edit
Wow, the below is kinda true, but the real issue is you didn't initialize state.  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    coin: {},
    hasLoaded: false,
    id: ''
  }
}
```

You could use lexical scoping and fix like this, this is a popular pattern to protect `this`.

Basically, when you use promises or functions from other libraries/ APIs you do not know what they have set their context inside the callback functions to.

In order to use the context you want, you keep the context you need saved in a variable within scope and reference it there `_this`, rather than by pointing to the context `this`.  I'd recommend reading 'you dont know js' to understand this concept further.

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('componentDidMount');
  const _this = this; 
  let _id = _this.props.match.params.id.toUpperCase();

  if ( _id != _this.state.id.toUpperCase() ) {
    axios.get('/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=' + _id + '&tsyms=USD')
      .then(response => {
        _this.setState({ id: _id }); //this == undefined
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I would add that `this` is not a variable. Closure does not apply on it. Also, I prefer `const that = this` :-)

Comment: Arrow functions explicitly preserve the lexical scope of `this` by definition, so inside the callback function passed to `then`, `_this === this` _should_ be true. The problem is coming from somewhere else (a bad transpiler perhaps?).

Comment: @JohnWeisz: I would expect `this` to be at least `axios`. Why do you think it should work?

Comment: @RaphaMex it is because its creating an anonymous function in the parameters field, thus having a lexical scope as `componentDidMount`

Comment: This is what I went with and it worked. It just seem the declaration of _this was extraneous
       const _this = this; 
       _this.setState({ id: _id })

Answer (score 4):

Solution 1: arrow functions..

```
requestSuccess = (resp) => {
  // let _currentcoin = { ...resp.data.RAW.BTC.USD, ticker: _id };
  this.setState({ id: _id });
}

componentDidMount() {
  console.log('componentDidMount');
  //const self = this; 
  let _id = this.props.match.params.id.toUpperCase();
  if (_id != this.state.id.toUpperCase()) {
     axios.get('/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=' + _id + '&tsyms=USD')
       .then(this.requestSuccess);
  }
}
```

Solution 2: binding

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('componentDidMount');
  //const self = this; 
  let _id = this.props.match.params.id.toUpperCase();
  if (_id != this.state.id.toUpperCase()) {
     axios.get('/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=' + _id + '&tsyms=USD')
       .then((resp) => {
          // let _currentcoin = { ...resp.data.RAW.BTC.USD, ticker: _id };
          this.setState({ id: _id });
     }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> When working with React.js, chances are you have faced a problem how
>   to access **this** from inside the promise.There is more than one solution to resolve this reference inside the
>   promise. The old approach would be setting the **self = this
>   reference** While this would work, the recommended solution, which is
>   more inline with ES6, would be to use an arrow function here:

```
class Component extends React.Component { 
  componentDidMount() {
    let component = this;
    axios.get('http://…').then(function(data) {
      component.setState( { name: data.blah } );
    });
  }
}
```

> The arrow syntax, as stated above, is a much smarter way to allow use
>   of this to make reference to React.Component classes, as we can see
>   below:

```
class Component extends React.Component { 
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://…').then(data => {
      this.setState( { name: data.blah } );
    });
  }
}
```

> Please note, instead of using 
>   function(data) { //body }, 
>   we used data => { //body }, and in this case this reference won’t get the promise instance back.