# ReactJS is calling the render method before it receives the data to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the main component loads, I send a GET request to my API to get all the objects that have certain value in a field called `"ship_name"`, this means more "builds" might arrive, so there will be more to be rendered. After loading the main Component, I have created a second component in the same file, called "Builds". As props, I send to this component this.state.builds, an array of objects.

**Better explanation:**

1. User inserts "ship_name" in a search bar
2. API looks for all builds that have that "ship_name"
3. All the builds are sent to the sub component
4. Using the "gears" (Gear Names) API looks for the file name and sends it back
5. ! React renders before the links arrive

```html
<Builds builds={this.state.builds} />
```

The structure of "builds" is like this

```js
[
    {
        "gears": [
            "Triple 410mm (10th Year Type Prototype)",
            "Triple 155mm (3rd Year Type)",
            "Twin 40mm Bofors STAAG Mk II",
            "High Performance Fire Control Radar",
            "Type 1 Armor Piercing Shell"
        ],
        "rarities": [
            "o",
            "o",
            "o",
            "o",
            "o"
        ],
        "_id": "5eac7b450e64096b082f4c43",
        "ship_name": "Gascogne",
        "pv": "e"
    },
    {
        "gears": [
            "Triple 410mm (10th Year Type Prototype)",
            "Triple 155mm (3rd Year Type)",
            "Twin 40mm Bofors STAAG Mk II",
            "High Performance Fire Control Radar",
            "Type 1 Armor Piercing Shell"
        ],
        "rarities": [
            "o",
            "o",
            "o",
            "o",
            "o"
        ],
        "_id": "5f131d6e2e3f16ef3de48e4f",
        "ship_name": "Gascogne",
        "pv": "e"
    }
]
```

Everything works till this point.

```js
render() {
        return (
            this.props.builds.map((build) => (
                <div className="container" key={uuidv4()}>
                    <img src={"/img/gears/" + this.getGearData(build.gears[0])} className={build.rarities[0] + " gI g1"}></img><div className={"t t1"}>{build.gears[0]}</div>
                    <img src={"/img/gears/" + this.getGearData(build.gears[1])} className={build.rarities[1] + " gI g2"}></img><div className={"t t2"}>{build.gears[1]}</div>
                    <img src={"/img/gears/" + this.getGearData(build.gears[2])} className={build.rarities[2] + " gI g3"}></img><div className={"t t3"}>{build.gears[2]}</div>
                    <img src={"/img/gears/" + this.getGearData(build.gears[3])} className={build.rarities[3] + " gI g4"}></img><div className={"t t4"}>{build.gears[3]}</div>
                    <img src={"/img/gears/" + this.getGearData(build.gears[4])} className={build.rarities[4] + " gI g5"}></img><div className={"t t5"}>{build.gears[4]}</div>
                </div>
            ))

        )
    }

/*------------------------------*/

getGearData(gear_name) {
        let requestString = encodeURI('http://localhost:5000/gears/one?q=' + gear_name)
        let data;
        Axios.get(requestString)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data[0].image_link)
                data = res.data[0].image_link
            })

        return data

        /* what */
    }
```

What happens here is that while I am rendering, at the same time I am trying to get the URL of the images. The GET methods works, in fact the console.log prints the actual name of the file

```
32200.png gear.component.js:76 
26600.png gear.component.js:76 
1260.png gear.component.js:76 
600.png gear.component.js:76 
34180.png gear.component.js:76
```

but on the SRC the result is ***"/img/gears/undefined"***. One thing that I can't understand is why all the results are printed 2 times, but that's not much of a problem since in the end the things get rendered only once correctly.

I have tried to use many methods, state, Promises (even if I haven't really understood how those work), it's the first time I'm really stuck like this. The fact is that the main component uses the "ship_name" to get the file name of the "ship_icon" and the "faction_icon" and it gives no problem, probably because I use the state there.

Here's an idea of how it looks like right now
[image]

And here's an idea of how it should look like
[image]

I completed this personal project once using php and SQL, now I am trying to do it with React and MongoDB.

Comment: This piece of code has many problems. I think you should first learn about asynchronous JavaScript. Your `Axios.get()` call is async and you're returning `data` before even it's fetched. State management is the second thing. Your fetched data should be stored in component state. Thirdly, you need to call your APIs in `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook or it's equivalent React hook. Clearing the concepts is more important here. Just a solution to this question won't help much, IMHO!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Then, specifically with React: [How to set state of response from axios in react](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41194866/1218980)

Comment: Then, [looping inside JSX would help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22876978/1218980). [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63022336/1218980) below also shows you how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### NOTE: you should be making the calls to fetch image URLs during the process that retrieves and/or sets the builds in the first place, this data structure is a sign of a poor design; now, that said:

1. React is a **reactive** library. It only *reacts* to changes in data that it is monitoring.
2. You can't mix asynchronous and synchronous functions and expect everything to wait.

when you call `getGearData(gear_name)` here is a rough rundown of what is happening *in the order it is happening*

1. you call `getGearData` with variable `gear_name`
2. a modifiable variable `requestString` is declared and set to `encodeURI('http://localhost:5000/gears/one?q=' + gear_name)` (side note, this should be `const` as it's not being modified
3. a modifiable variable `data` is declared
4. an asynchronous request is *started* to retrieve data from the server
5. a reference to the *current* value of `data` is returned to the caller
6. react renders
7. your request finishes
8. the local variable `data` is set *within* the function scope

#### you have to wait for async operations

there are a number of ways to do this. Here's an example using placeholder images

```js
const placeholder = "https://link.to/placeholder-image.png"

class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { images: {} }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.builds != this.props.builds) {
      this.fetchImages()
    }
  }

  fetchImages() {
    this.props.builds.forEach(build => {
      build.gears.forEach(gear => {
        Axios.get(encodeURI('http://localhost:5000/gears/one?q=' + gear_name))
          .then(res => {
            const link = res.data[0].image_link 
            console.log(link)
            this.setState(state => { images: { ...state.images, [gear]: link } })
          })
      })
    })
  }

  mapGears = (gears) =>
    gears.map(
      (gear, i) =>
        <img
          src={this.state.images[gear] || placeholder}
          className={`t t${i}`}
          key={`${gear}.${i}`}
        />
    )

  render() {
    return (
      this.props.builds.map((build) => (
        <div className="container" key={build._id}>
          {this.mapGears(build.gears)}
        </div>
      ))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I changed some small things and now it works wonderfully, here's how it looks [now](https://i.imgur.com/ZCAWVoU.png). 
Before I keep going I better study promises and asynchronous JS, I can clearly see what is my code and what is not.

Answer (score -1):

That's because `Axios.get` is an *asynchronous* function, so you are returning variables before their data has been set.

I'd also say it's a poor design, it'd be a lot better to separate the concerns of fetching asynchronous data and rendering, eg.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const containerToRender = (<></>);

    await Promise.all(
      this.props.builds.map(async (build) => {
        const container = <container ... key={build._id} />
        await Promise.all(build.gears.map(async (gear, i) => {
          container.children.push(<img src={"/img/gears/" + await this.getGearData(gear)} className={`${build.rarities[i]} gI g${i + 1}"} key={`img.${gear}.${i} />)
          container.children.push(<div className={`t t${i + 1}`} key={`div.${gear}.${i}>{gear}</div>)
        })
        containerToRender.children.push(container)
      })

    this.setState({ containerToRender });
}

getGearData(gear_name) {
  const requestString = encodeURI('http://localhost:5000/gears/one?q=' + gear_name)

  return Axios.get(requestString).then(res => res.data[0].image_link)
}

render() {
    return (this.state.containerToRender);
}
```

Comment: `await` would do absolutely nothing to solve the problem, it's only syntactic sugar for promises.  you still have to find a way to get the asyncronous data **outside** of the rendering process

Comment: And storing JSX nodes in the state is an anti-pattern.