# How to use react faq component with data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm using this component in my React Js web application: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-faq-component.

```
const data = {
    title: "FAQ (How it works)",
    rows: [
        {
            title: "Lorem ipsum",
            content: "Dolor sit amet",
        },
    ],
};
```

I need to populate "rows:" with data retrieved by my API.

This is my code:

```
class Faqs extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      faqs: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let category = 'caategory1';
    axios.get('https://myurl/api/faqs/'+category).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        faqs: response.data
      })
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { faqs } = this.state;
    const styles = {
      titleTextColor: "black",
      rowTitleColor: "black",
      rowContentColor: 'grey',
    }
    const config = {
      animate: true,
    }

    let data = {
      title: 'FAQS (How it works)',
      rows: [
        // Here is where I'm trying to print the json data from the API
        faqs.map(
            (faq, index) => {
                return (
                    `{title: ${faq.title}, content: ${faq.content}},`
                )
            }
        )
      ]
    }
}
```

I guess it's something about escaping but I'm a very beginner with React, so if anybody could help, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your render statement never returns. Also, you never import the FAQ component you say you are attempting to use. Finally, you probably [need to stabilize the value of "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194866/how-to-set-state-of-response-from-axios-in-react)

All together, the code would be something like this (haven't tested it):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Faq from "react-faq-component";
import axios from 'axios';

const styles = {titleTextColor: "blue", rowTitleColor: "blue"};
const config = {};

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        faqs: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let category = 'caategory1';
    let me = this;
    axios.get('https://myurl/api/faqs/'+category).then(response => {
      //Using "me" because I think "this" refers to the axios object
      me.setState({
          faqs: response.data
      })
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Faq data={this.state.faqs} styles={styles} config={config} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No my friend, "rows:" needs to be populated like this:  rows: [
        {
            title: "Lorem ipsum",
            content: "Dolor sit amet",
        },
    ]. I've just posted a part of the code, but of course I've imported axios and the faq component.