# How to fix my code so that I can use the data from componentDidMount (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get data from an api so that I can display it when the page is loaded. I want to pass this data onto the Featured component. The api GET request works, however, I'm getting the error 'res' in not defined no-undef. I'm guessing it's because it's an async function and the state is being told to change before the data from the api has come back. However, I get the same error even if I take away the async and await. I have a few questions regarding this:

1. What is causing the issue?
2. How would you fix the issue?
3. Am I correct in using componentDidMount for what I'm trying to do?

Code is posted bellow. Thanks in advance!

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { featuredMovies: [] };

    async componentDidMount() {
        await axios.get('apiurl').then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
      });

        this.setState({ featuredMovies: res.data });
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container section">
                <Featured />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: @EmileBergeron I thought that first. But I guess since it's React, we need to handle differently like how I have answered.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman there's absolutely nothing react specific here, React is just JavaScript anyway.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Agreed. Alright then.

Comment: For React specific implementation, there is also: [How to set state of response from axios in react](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41194866/1218980).

Comment: @EmileBergeron Great, this new question is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost right. Just change this part:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const res = await axios.get('apiurl');
  this.setState({ featuredMovies: res.data });
}
```

So to answer your questions:

1. What is causing the issue?
   *The problem with your code is that you don't have `res` out of the function.*
2. How would you fix the issue?
   *Using the above solution.*
3. Am I correct in using componentDidMount for what I'm trying to do?
   *Almost right. Your approach is right.*

Comment: Of course! thanks for the clarification

Comment: @BoJack I am in London as well. Hello! 