# Get RIOT API data from proxy server with React

Tags: reactjs, api, proxy, axios, riot-games-api

I'm currently working on a personal project where I wanna display all the skins from Valorant (Riot games FPS).
So I'm building a React web app and a nodejs [backend proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsxI5.png) server to request skins' data from RIOT API ( https://developer.riotgames.com/apis#val-content-v1/GET_getContent) and send them to my client side app.

The problem is : [I manage to get the data on my backend server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8UfL.png)
but when I try to request my [backend server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrFaF.png) from my react app.js, I don't [know how to put these data into my application state and display their name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqDhY.png)

this is what i get in localhost:3000 : [App Component developer tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytRpk.png) / [Network developer tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmGjQ.png)

I watched several tutorials on how to do this and tried but it didn't work. Is there something I'm missing or misunderstood ? Don't be afraid to ask me more details if needed, that's my first question asked on StackOverflow I hope I did it right :)

EDIT: I modified the getSkins() method in my App.js to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68e1o.png) as suggested but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set state of response from axios in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194866/how-to-set-state-of-response-from-axios-in-react)

Comment: @RenanSouza sadly it doesn't, I edited the question so you can see I changed my code to what's suggested on the other topic